# Подскажите как установить слушатель нажатия на кнопку и как с ним взаимодействовать? OnTouchListener нужен Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, ontouchlistener

Просто покажите пример. Есть кнопка bt1 и текствью text_1
как по нажатию кнопку изменить текствью? Используя вот эту конструкцию?

```
bt1.setOnTouchListener(Listeners.onTouch) 
object Listeners {
        val onTouch = View.OnTouchListener { v: View, event: MotionEvent ->
            //Вот тут что мне надо сделать ? Я взял код с английского оверфлоу. Только учусь. Не могу
            //понять как взаимодействовать.
            return@OnTouchListener false
        } }
```

Comment: попробуйте не брать код с английского оверфлоу, а почитать учебники, где разбираются различные примеры, чтобы получить хоть какое-то понимание того, как все работает. На взятии кода с оверфлоу много не напрограммируешь.

Comment: Начал изучать и в ходе изучения понадобилось, у меня есть одна черта искать ответ на свой вопрос, даже не имея никакого представления в тематике вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

`View.OnTouchListener` обычно применяется для собственных шаблонов взаимодействия с UI компонентом, для обычного нажатия уже есть готовый шаблон, который вызывает `View.OnClickListener`.
Любой обработчик необходимо определять так, чтобы из него были доступны все необходимые обьекты либо данные либо UI элементы.

Обычно это делают с помощью анонимной лямбды. Пример:

```
...
text_1.visibility = View.VISIBLE // тут у вас доступен нужный TextView
bt1.setOnClickListener {
  text_1.text = "Кнопка нажата"            
}
...
```

Ваш пример с `object` тоже Ок, только многое зависит от того где этот `object` в коде расположен и что из него "видно".